# Why don't these Japanese characters line up vertically?

Tags: css

Why don't these Japanese characters line up vertically?  I want the Romaji underneath the Kanji, I don't want vertical text.

```css
.result {
  margin-left: 4px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="result">
    <div>
      <div>朝</div>
      <div>asa</div>
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="result">
    <div>
      <div>もちろん</div>
      <div>mochiron</div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid : `<span>` element are not alowed to contains any `<div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making vertical Japanese text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652227/making-vertical-japanese-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it

```css
.result {
  margin-left: 4px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="result">    
      <div>朝</div>
      <div>asa</div>
    </div>

  <div class="result">    
      <div>もちろん</div>
      <div>mochiron</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `writing-mode` css property to display vertical text.

e.g.:

```css
.vertical-text {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* You need to choose a font that supports vertical text */
}
```

In this example I use `writing-mode: vertical-rl` to set the direction of the text flow, `text-orientation: upright` to control the orientation of characters within the vertical text and `line-height: 1.5` to control the spacing between characters.